# Finding braces in string (java)

Tags: arrays, string

I need to make a program which will check if braces are paired in string and then write the result (true or false).

My current idea is tofind all braces in that string, add them to char array.  Then I would just sum up all braces in array as an integer.  If this sum is divisible by sums of their numbers in integer (example `{}` the sum of these braces is 123+125 = 248 ) with 248 i would control pairing of those `{}` braces and similarly i would do that with remaining braces. Is it good approach or does exist anything more powerful?

But I've run into a problem even before this idea.  I can't detect the braces in string then put detected braces to char array.  How can I detect those braces?

Comment: what language are you working on?

Comment: sorry, forgot to add it after reediting it. (java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a simple code will do the trick:

```
boolean braceCounter(String yourString)
{
   int braceCount=0;
   for(int i=0;i<yourString.length;i++)
   {
      if(yourString.charAt(i) == '{')
          braceCount++;
      if(yourString.charAt(i) == '}')
          braceCount--;
      if(braceCount < 0)
          return false;
    }
    if(braceCount != 0)
       return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: How do i expand this task to ensure that there are paired braces (all types) and that they are in good order - example - {[()]} but not {[(])}. This solution won't do this thing.